# Objectif Function Gams

Tags: function, mathematical-optimization, gams-math

I'm beginner with gams , so i'm trying to create this new function into gams

MAX   (Σ(t=0-->2020) (Vusage (t )  * pusage   * 1-busage  ))

where pusage and tusage are two constants and Vusage (t ) is a function depending on t incremental.

How can I write the code of gams
Thanks for all

Comment: This should give you a good start: https://www.gams.com/39/docs/UG_Tutorial.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you get good replies on your question, showing code that you have tried can really help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should first recognize your set (t),
after that you can write your objective as below:

```
z=e=sum(t$(ord(t)<2020), (Vusage(t)*pusage*(1-busage) );
```